# Склонение по группам

Tags: склонение, морфология

Как просклонять существительные единственного числа по группам: *зима, карта, Витя и конь, рот, море*?

Comment: Данил, что вы понимаете под *склонением по группам*? Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно открыть учебник и посмотреть, как склоняются существительные 1 и 2 склонения. Если это имелось под "группами".